# React-Leaflet getting started

Tags: react-leaflet

Is it supposed to look like this?

I followed https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/example/components/simple.js and the homepage quickstart.

[image: Sucky map]

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "leaflet": "^1.3.4",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-leaflet": "^2.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing a Leaflet CSS (or JS) or both ...

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the docs of "react-leaflet" it states the following:

> You will notably need to add its CSS to your page to render the map properly, and set the height of the  container (full text: https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/setup.html#docsNav)

You can try to set the width and height of the `Map` element (e.g., I need the width as 100% of the parent container and fixed height of 450px):

```
<Map center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom} style={{width: '100%', height: 450}}>
...
```

This would give you a box with zooming options but you won't see the map itself as you're now missing the map styles so you need to import it:

```
@import '~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

You also can add the CSS in your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing Leaflet CSS and/or width & height of map container.

Or you might need to use `map.invalidateSize()` because your container size changed, at it will update map to fit new container size.